# Accessing variable from ActionListener and transferring it to new method

Tags: java, string, swing, methods, actionlistener

I've been doing Java for a little bit, but even still sometimes formatting of methods and variables can confuse me, depending on the circumstances. I feel like this is probably a simple fix, but for some reason I'm stuck on it. I have an `ActionListener` attached to a button in a `JDialog` . When this `ActionListener` method is activated, it creates a string `dateAndTime` , as well as several components related to the `TimerTask` class from the `Timer` package (I'm considering removing these anyway in lieu of a `ScheduledExecutorService` , but never mind that). I understand that I can declare a global variable in my class outside of any methods, and I can create parameters that are passed to methods whose values are updated locally inside those methods, but I want to know: how can I take the values of these strings, whose pointers are given values upon the pressing of the button, and use them in other, future methods?

The code for the `ActionListener` is below.

```
getMessageAndTime.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String mm = month.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String dd = day.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String yy = year.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String hr = hour.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String min = minute.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String mornOrNight = am_pm.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    String dateAndTime = mm +"-" + dd +"-" + yy + " " + hr +":" + min + " " + mornOrNight;
                    dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm aa");

                    try {
                        date = dateFormatter.parse(dateAndTime);
                    } catch (ParseException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    timer = new Timer();
                    String contents = message.getText();
                    if (contents.equals("")) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(d2, "Announcement field is blank. Please try again.",
                                "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply declare your variables outside the scope of this method.

```
private String mm = "";
private String dd = "";

 public void methodX()
 {
     getMessageAndTime.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    mm = month.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    dd = day.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    ....
                    ....
                    ....
                }
            });
 }

public void methodY(){
//Now you can access 'mm' and 'dd' here
System.out.println(mm);
}
```